# Angular 2 *ngFor and dynamic field

Tags: angular, ngfor

Here a little code:

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields">
  <div>
    <label>{{field}}</label><input name="item.field" [(ngModel)]="item.field">
  </div>
</div>
```

"fields" is a list of string equals to each field of "item" object
"item" is an object with several property.

i want to generate a dynamic form using this simple *ngFor and write something like:

"item.field"

Am i doing it wrong ?

Thx you !

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?? Any error logs ?? Please post output images and if possible error logs. @user3178486

Comment: what is structure of fields array. what is item object here

Comment: The issue is ... 
                    <label>{{field}}</label><input name="item.field" [(ngModel)]="item.field">

shows nothing.

Actually, item = {"name":"undef","id":0,"desc":"undef"}
and fields is ["name","id","desc"]

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
<label>{{item[field]}}</label><input name="item[field]" [(ngModel)]="item[field]">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using square bracket notation:

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields">
    <div>
        <label>{{field}}</label><input name="item[field]" [(ngModel)]="item[field]">
    </div>
</div>
```